# Parental Control in Android

Tags: android, parental-control

How to implement parental control in my application i.e when my application starts, all the other applications should stop running.
plz help me.

Comment: How does stopping other applications provide parental controls?

Comment: That's sounds your program behaves like a virus. As far as I know, every process has its own UID and android uses Linux kernel to manage the processes. You do not have the previlege to stop other processes. If the phone is rooted or your app has been certified by the system, perhaps it is possible.

Comment: Huangs comment is correct. This is only possible if the phone is rooted and your app has super user privileges. This will not be possible on a generic device that loads your application from the market.

Comment: Breaking other applications is not parental control. You are supposed to use the facilities specifically provided by the OS for parental control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.Retrieve the name of running processes and their UIDs and then kill those processes which you want to stop.e.g If u want to stop browser app you can do this in this way.

```
ActivityManager servMng;
servMng = (ActivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> list = servMng.getRunningAppProcesses();
                if(list != null){
                 for(int i=0;i<list.size();++i){
                  if("com.android.browser".matches(list.get(i).processName)){
                   int pid = android.os.Process.getUidForName("com.android.browser");
                         android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
                  }else{
                   mTextVIew.append(list.get(i).processName + "\n");
                  }
                 }
                }
```

Comment: hey salman have you done with parental control in your application?? if yes please help me to do so.

Comment: its not working, This solution not killing current visible application.